# Keno Game Question

Tags: combinatorics

This question comes from a video keno game called Gumball Falls.  There are 80 balls in the tank and 20 are drawn.  The question pertains to the 4-spot, more specifically the frequency of the 3 out of 4.  My math puts this frequency at 23.12.  But there is a countdown meter and any time I go 60 games without hitting a 3 out of 4 I am automatically awarded the 3 out of 4. This is about 2.6 cycles.  That would somewhat change the overall frequency of 23.12 to something a little less.  But that math is way over my head.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it exactly three or at least three?

Comment: How do you want to combine the chances of hitting three with not hitting in 60 tries?  Do you want the average number of wins in 60 tries?  I don't understand what you mean by 2.6 cycles.

Comment: It is for hitting exactly 3 out of the 4 numbers.  I got the 2.6 cycles by dividing 60 by the normal 3 out of 4 frequency which is 23.12.  In gambler's parlance, we call the frequency of occurance of an event a "cycle." For example, playing optimal strategy for 9/6 Jacks or Better video poker the cycle (frequency of occurence) for making a royal flush is 40,390 games.  This video keno game, Gumball Falls offers short term exploitable advantages.  I need to know the exact frequency of the 3 out of 4.  Normally the frequency for the 3 out of 4 is 23.12:

Comment: Normally, the 3 out of 4 cycle is 23.12.  But since I am automatically awarded the 3 out of 4 if I miss it for 60 games I figure the frequency of 3 out of 4 in this game is a little less than 23.12....say 22.5 or something like that.  I just don't know the mathmatical formula for calculating it. That's why I'm asking for your help.  Thanks.  Mickey

Answer (score 1):

The chance of getting exactly three on one draw is $\frac {{20 \choose 3}{60 \choose 1}}{{80 \choose 4}}=\frac {3420}{79079}\approx 0.04325\approx 1/23.123$  The chance of four is only $\frac {{20 \choose 4}}{{80 \choose 4}}=\frac {969}{316316}\approx 0.00306$, so it looks like you only count the times you get exactly three.  The chance you go $60$ in a row without a hit is $\left(\frac {79079-3420}{79079}\right)^{60}\approx 0.0705$

Added:  In $60$ tries without the meter you expect $60 \cdot 0.04325=2.595$ wins.  By the linearity of expectation, the countdown meter increases this to an expectation of $2.670$  If we assume the meter resets to zero after $60$ (not after each win), in the long run you will win once in $60/2.67\approx 22.472$ games.

Comment: Yes, the meter resets any time you hit a 3 out of 4 or you go 60 games.  Thanks for the help, Ross.

Comment: Then you should think of the chance of the next win as a geometric distribution, but with the sum limited to $60$ (with a guaranteed win) instead of $\infty$.  Can you solve it now?  I think I have provided significant guidance.  If you still have questions, please make them clear.

Comment: Ross, you are giving me more credit for my math ability than I deserve.  I have no idea what a geometric distribution is.  LOL!

Answer (score 0):

The probability of getting exactly k out of your 4 numbers is (4,k)*(80-k,20)/(80,20). The probabilities for exactly 0,1,2,3,4 out of 4 are: {0.308321, 0.432732, 0.212635, 0.0432479, 0.00306339}.

Comment: @RossMillikan.  Thanks, I changed my original answer to the ( I hope) correct answer.

Comment: I agree with your values for 3 and 4.  To get the usual binomial formatting you can use {4 \choose k} between dollar signs to get ${4 \choose k}$ Som general help on MathJax is [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)